# How to make real time notifications from DB to local computer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm doing a web page, where you can sign to subscribe list, to get notifications about some news. Everything works, but i want to change something. When i enter an email, and submit it, i'm getting redirect to a new page (email.php), where I'm getting an alert that inform me, if email has been added to database where I store all emails. I want to do the same alert without refreshing page ( make alerts on the same site as we include email )

I've been doing this on AJAX, but I'm not very good at JavaScript ( I'm kinda new in JS ). I think I might did something wrong, but I couldn't see it.

Below is some code

//HTML

```html
<form method="POST" action="email.php" name="email-db" id="email-db">
                    <input type="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    <button  type="submit" class="submit" >&#10148;</button>
                </form>
```

//PHP

```php
<?php
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
    if (!empty($email)){
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbusername ="root";
        $dbpassword ="";
        $dbname = "email";
        $alert1 = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Email has been written to subscribe list!\");</script>";
        $alertredirect = "<script type='text/javascript'>
           window.location = 'index.html'
      </script>";
        $alert2 = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(\"Your email is already on our subscribe list!\");</script>";

        $conn = new mysqli ($host,$dbusername, $dbpassword , $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()){
            die('Connection problem('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error()); 
        }
        else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `email` (`email_id`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$email');";
            if ($conn->query($sql)){
                echo "$alert1";
                echo "$alertredirect";
            }
            else{
                echo "$alert2";
                echo "$alertredirect";
            }
            $conn->close();   
    }}
?>
```

As you can see ( on email.php ) I did redirects - but as I said - all of this alerts need to happens on index.html - without refreshing or redirecting.

Thanks for support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change your submit button to a `type=button` so it doesn't submit the form and do a postback (there are other methods)
2. Remove javascript/html from your php handler and return data, eg a simple `true`/`false`
3. add a js click event handler that calls `$.ajax`,

eg:

```
$("button.submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: your_url, 
        data: { email: $(".email").val() }, 
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result ? "Email saved" : "Already exists");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. So on PHP file i should add just : $result = true / false where I had echo "alert" ?
2. I should add JS click event on button like that ? : onclick="$.ajax" 
Anyway : thanks for advice

Comment: You don't have to, but it makes it easier when returning an ajax request to only return data (or pre-formatted HTML).  Returning javascript (script tag from php) is a little messy (IMO) and harder to work with.   Returning true/false means you can act on that information, eg if true then just show a tick while if false show the message and set focus back to the input.  If you just had a message, you'd then have to *parse* that message, which isn't a good idea.  You could return a JSON object from your php with both success flag and a message (and/or any other info)

Comment: Well, it works - I'm getting response, but I'm getting always False ( Email already exist ) - Do you have any tips what could I do wrong?

Comment: Change `success: function(result) {` to `success: function(result) { console.log(result)` to see what jquery is receiving.  Otherwise it's whatever your php is doing - can you step through?

Comment: I'm don't get anything - just infromation in circle about how many messages I have from index.html and number of line where ```success: function(result) { console.log(result)``` is placed

Comment: The number in the circle in the browser debugger is how many times that message has occurred - they do this rather than fill up the console with the same message repeated.   Can't really help you without seeing a working example.

Comment: I can send you a files with page if you have more time and will to help 
[Here is website](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/bj685b3mk7cad/webpage)

Answer (score 0):

`<form method="POST" action="email.php" name="email-db" id="email-db">
 <input type="email" class="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
 <button  type="submit" class="submit" >&#10148;</button>
</form>`

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{

   // This will help you to diable the defaut property of the form, And stops refresing on the submit 

   if(event && event.preventDefault){
      event.preventDefault();
   }

   let formData = new FormData(form)

   //This code will iterate data from the input elements from your form
   let postData = {};

   for(let [key, val] of formData.entries()){
    if(val) postData[key] = val;
   }


   postData(event.target.action, postData)
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))) 
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
})

function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
        body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    })
    .then(response => response.json()); // parses JSON response into native Javascript objects 
}
```

After this will post data to the server for your use and then you send data back to you call.

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly for you:

**FRONT-END (JAVASCRIPT)**
In the front-end, you can use AJAX to send your request like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#email-db').on('submit', function(){
           let email = $('.email').val();
           $.ajax({
              url: "email.php"
              type: 'post',
              data: { 'email': email },
              success: function(response){
                 alert(response);
              }
           });
       });
}
```

**SERVER-SIDE (PHP)**
In the server-side, you can use PHP to return your alert message

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $host = 'localhost';
        $dbusername = 'root';
        $dbpassword = '';
        $dbname = 'email';
        $alert1 = 'Email has been written to subscribe list';
        $alert2 = 'Your email is already on our subscribe list';
        $conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connection problem('.mysqli_connect_errno().')'.mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `email` (`email_id`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$email');";
            return $conn->query($sql) ? $alert1 : $alert2;
        }
    }
?>
```